# stm8s cco flag never set

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm8

I have a discovery stm8s003k board and when I tested a program for cco capability it seems cco will never be stable and program always remain in line: `while(CLK_GetFlagStatus(CLK_FLAG_CCORDY) == FALSE);` 
code and more explain is in detail.

I tested it with below code and I even change pre-scalers for lower and higher frequency, I also check it with external crystal (and change the code) but it remains in `while(CLK_GetFlagStatus(CLK_FLAG_CCORDY) == FALSE);` forever.

When I debug the code and step over in debugger environment after the program enables **CCOEN** bit the output will start and frequency is just true. but both flags **CCORDY** and **CCOBSY** remains set (**CCOR=0x69** in debugger) and it always remain in while loop. My code is:

```
#include "STM8S.h"
#define LED_pin                      GPIO_PIN_0
#define LED_port                     GPIOD

void setup(void);
void clock_setup(void);
void GPIO_setup(void);

void main(void)
{
  setup();
  GPIO_WriteLow(LED_port, LED_pin);
  while(TRUE){};
}

void setup(void)
{
  clock_setup();
  GPIO_setup();
}

void clock_setup(void)
{
  CLK_DeInit();
  CLK_HSECmd(DISABLE);
  CLK_LSICmd(DISABLE);
  CLK_HSICmd(ENABLE);

  while(CLK_GetFlagStatus(CLK_FLAG_HSIRDY) == FALSE);

  CLK_ClockSwitchCmd(ENABLE);
  CLK_HSIPrescalerConfig(CLK_PRESCALER_HSIDIV8);
  CLK_SYSCLKConfig(CLK_PRESCALER_CPUDIV4);
  CLK_ClockSwitchConfig(CLK_SWITCHMODE_AUTO, CLK_SOURCE_HSI,
  DISABLE, CLK_CURRENTCLOCKSTATE_ENABLE);
  CLK_PeripheralClockConfig(CLK_PERIPHERAL_I2C, DISABLE);
  CLK_PeripheralClockConfig(CLK_PERIPHERAL_SPI, DISABLE);
  CLK_PeripheralClockConfig(CLK_PERIPHERAL_UART1, DISABLE);
  CLK_PeripheralClockConfig(CLK_PERIPHERAL_AWU, DISABLE);
  CLK_PeripheralClockConfig(CLK_PERIPHERAL_ADC, DISABLE);
  CLK_PeripheralClockConfig(CLK_PERIPHERAL_TIMER1, DISABLE);
  CLK_PeripheralClockConfig(CLK_PERIPHERAL_TIMER2, DISABLE);
  CLK_PeripheralClockConfig(CLK_PERIPHERAL_TIMER4, DISABLE);
  CLK_CCOConfig(CLK_OUTPUT_CPU);
  CLK_CCOCmd(ENABLE);

  while(CLK_GetFlagStatus(CLK_FLAG_CCORDY) == FALSE);
}

void GPIO_setup(void)
{                              
  GPIO_DeInit(LED_port);
  GPIO_Init(LED_port, LED_pin, GPIO_MODE_OUT_OD_HIZ_FAST);
}
```